# Need a strategy to lookup property for dynamically generated dropdown component

Tags: java, wicket

I need to set the null value string for a dropDownChoice component. The default value for null choice is "Choose One", which is hardcoded in the Wicket AbstractSingleChoice class.

The usual way of overriding this is to define a property resource.

However my DropdownChoice component is dynamically generated at runtime, and added to a panel (which is within a datatable). The DropDownChoice is not specifically referenced in the markup.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to programmatically override the default null value string in this situation. It would be nice if the DropDownChoice constructor had an additional parameter for this.

Do I need to programmatically create a new property resource?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`AbstractSingleSelectChoice.getNullKey()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.html#getNullKey%28%29) and [`AbstractSingleSelectChoice.getNullValidKey()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.html#getNullValidKey%28%29) in order to make Wicket retrieve a localized resource from a .properties or .xml file that does not have the component id as part of the key. This is documented in this JIRA issue: [Open DropDownChoice null value internationalization key](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-2531)

For instance:

```
DropDownChoice ddc = new DropDownChoice(id, model, choices){
   @Override
   protected String getNullKey(){ return "customDdcNullValue"; }
   @Override
   protected String getNullValidKey(){ return "customDdcNullValue"; }
}
```

Will retrieve the `<option>`'s text from the `customDdcNullValue` property.

These methods seem to have been added in version 1.4.4, if you're on 1.3, you could always use an `IChoiceRenderer` with the `DropDownChoice` that returns the proper String in the case of `null` value. Note that you could retrieve it from resources (with `getString()`, or `StringResourceModel`), or grab the value from database/cache if necessary. This may depend on how are you already localizing the choices for non-null values.

Also, you could use the source code of [`AbstractSingleSelectChoice.getDefaultChoice()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.8/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.java#AbstractSingleSelectChoice.getDefaultChoice%28java.lang.Object%29) to roll your own `DropDownChoice` with this behavior.

**UPDATE**: Another way of handling this is to provide your own custom value that represents `null`, or no-choice. Just remember to use `setNullValid(false)` on the `DropDownChoice` to prevent `null` from appearing when there is a selected value, and initialize the ddc's model with your no-selection value when you still don't know its value in order to avoid Wicket provide `null` in the `getDefaultChoice()` call.

When defining the value for your no-selection option, pay special attention to this part of [`AbstractSingleSelectChoice.getDefaultChoice()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.8/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.java#301):

```
// Null is not valid. Is it selected anyway?
if ((selected == null) || getNoSelectionValue().equals(selected) ||
      selected.equals(EMPTY_STRING))
{
```

Take into account that `getNoSelectionValue()` returns `-1`, so please do not use `-1`, or an empty string, as your custom null value. I learnt this the hard way, believe me, it's not pleasing.

Comment: Nice answer. We're on version 1.4.17, and DropDownChoice doesn't have the getNullKey methods. I think they were added in 1.4.18.

Comment: Actually, thinking about this further. I could just add another option to the list of choices e.g. "Not set"?

Comment: Sorry, yes you're correct. I understand what you are suggesting. Thanks for the code example.

Comment: Actually Xavi, I'm going to use my idea of adding an extra "Use default value" to the list of choices. It's the path of least resistance for me. But I'll accept your answer as technically correct.

Comment: @AndrewFielden I've updated the answer, now taking into account your idea. Note the part about selecting the value for your no-selection option. Don't use an empty String or -1!

Answer (score 0):

You should use localisation feature to achieve it. There is a method `org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.IStringResourceLoader.loadStringResource(org.apache.wicket.Component,java.lang.String)` which returns a string value to display for a given component. The string will be a resource key, for your case it is the "nullValid" string, IIRC.
So, you can implement your custom resource manager which will pick data from a database instead of `.properties` files.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use an `IChoiceRenderer`? How would this be implemented? Would it have any advantage over `IChoiceRenderer`?

Comment: Hm, not sure. Probably IChoiceRenderer is easier for the particular issue. However, IStringResourceLoader is more powerful, it could provide universal solution for database based dynamic interface.